# How can I get DataGridView combobox cell value to be written in the MessageBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to read the the combobox column as shown in the picture, i've tried using
string mode = dt.Rows[0]["Mode"].ToString();
But it doesn't work, it read the USID column instead.
How to read the combobox value?

[datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKYjJ.jpg)

```
    private void getmode()
```

{

```
//from here 
var modelist = new List<string>() { "Reg0", "Basic", "Extended" };
dgvmode.DataSource = modelist;
dgvmode.HeaderText = "Mode";
dtDataGridView.Columns.Add(dgvmode); 
// until here, i've create a combobox column in my datatable
string mode = dt.Rows[i]["Mode"].ToString(); // this line got error, it can't read the "Mode" column and say it is not exist, but in my picture, it is exist as a combobox column.

Messagebox.Show(mode); // here to show i get the combobox value
```

}

Comment: Perhaps adding some code and debugging details would provide sufficient context for an answer.

Comment: There is presumably some underlying ID associated with the text in that cell. That's what you're going to see in the bound data source, not that text.

Comment: The code you have provided is going to give you the value in the `Mode` column of the first row of a `DataTable`. That's it, that's all. If you're not getting what you expect then your expectations are wrong. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @jak Did you try FindControl like Rows[0].FindControl("ComboboxId") ?

Comment: @donstack did you mean mydatagridview.rows[0].FindControl("Comboboxid")?
Since i cant find any findcontrol function if i use datatable or datagridview

Comment: @John I just want to know how to read the combobox cell's value, since i want to add a few of rows in the datatable. In my picture, there is a "Mode" column, but it is a combobox column, hence there is an error to read the "Mode" column.

Comment: Here: `dt.Rows[i]["Mode"]`, you need to specify the Column's `Name`, not the text of the Header. Or use the ordinal, e.g., `dt.Rows[i][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datatable is unable to reada datagridview feature, thus, when i using

yourdatatable.Rows[i]["Mode"].ToString();

it will comes out an error (something likie "Mode" column doesnt exist)

even you change the "Mode" to an integer that indicate the column you want to read, it will automatically read the column that create by datatable only. For example :
yourdatatable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
it  wont read the combobox column and it will read normal column instead (will not read combobox column ("Mode"), which is the first column. But it will read the column ("USID"), which is the second column).

then, i need to use datagridview like the code below to read the combobox value:
yourDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()